# Broadcast DNS name visible to PC but not phone

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi which my PC can reach at `http://raspberrypi.local`.

My Android phone (which is on the same WiFi network and has mobile data switched off) gets `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAN`.

Why can my PC but not my phone reach the Pi?

Comment: Based on some simple Googling, it appears that Android may not support the mechanism you're using for DNS resolution. A simple solution is to just set up your own local DNS server and make it the one your router uses. Then any device connected to the router should be able to access the device name and IP mappings you set up.

Comment: I was able to access my raspberry by it's DNS until recently. After a restart (without specific updates) it's only accesable via its IP on android devices, but still via DNS on browsers on computers..

Answer (score 3):

The problem is explained in the post
[How to get mDNS working for Chrome on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/how-to-get-mdns-working-for-chrome-on-android)

Android doesn't have any support for Bonjour (aka mDNS, aka
zeroconf networking) in standard name resolution.

Unless the Android app you're using explicitly uses an mDNS library,
it will not see `raspberrypi.local`.

You'll need to discover your Raspberry Pi's IP address (192.168.xxx.xxx) and use that.